# How to fill a NULL in a column with the value of a different line based on same id of a different table

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, null

This is my SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    GXFINENTRYLINES.GXID, GXFINENTRY.GXID FINENTRYGXID, 
    GXTRADER.GXNAME, GXFINENTRYLINES.GXLINENUM,  
    GXFINENTRYLINES.GXTRNVALUE  
FROM 
    GXFINENTRYLINES  
LEFT JOIN 
    GXTRADEENTRY ON GXFINENTRYLINES.GXTENTID = GXTRADEENTRY.GXID  
LEFT JOIN 
    GXFINENTRY ON GXFINENTRYLINES.GXFENTID = GXFINENTRY.GXID  
INNER JOIN 
    GXFINENTRYTYPE ON GXFINENTRY.GXFETPID = GXFINENTRYTYPE.GXID  
LEFT JOIN 
    GXTRADER ON GXFINENTRYLINES.GXTRDRID = GXTRADER.GXIDyour`
```

And the result is like this :

| GXFINENTRYLINES.GXID | FINENTRYGXID | GXNAME | LINENUM | GXTRNVAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BA4A846A-2D3E-7974-DC0B-018A02C26931 | D0CFE900-8A25-BF6E-1125-018A02C226F0 | NAME_A | -1 | 3800.00 |
| 5BBB6000-34FE-43B7-C173-018A02C27527 | D0CFE900-8A25-BF6E-1125-018A02C226F0 | NULL | 1 | 3300.00 |
| C8529015-DC40-EA1E-36A1-018A02E3F088 | D0CFE900-8A25-BF6E-1125-018A02C226F0 | NULL | 2 | 500.00 |
| BE224ED1-A770-62C3-DB71-0185DDB1B62C | 2E1CE68A-5D4A-BBD8-021F-0185DDB0CB13 | NAME_B | -1 | 2500.00 |
| 95F1F307-143F-8864-A987-0185DDB1F457 | 2E1CE68A-5D4A-BBD8-021F-0185DDB0CB13 | NULL | 1 | 2500.00 |

But what I try to find and I want as a result is to have the name in `GXNAME` and not `NULL` where `LINENUM <> -1` and where the id in column B (`FINENTRYGXID`) is the same.

The result should look like this:

| GXFINENTRYLINES.GXID | FINENTRYGXID | GXNAME | LINENUM | GXTRNVAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BA4A846A-2D3E-7974-DC0B-018A02C26931 | D0CFE900-8A25-BF6E-1125-018A02C226F0 | NAME_A | -1 | 3800.00 |
| 5BBB6000-34FE-43B7-C173-018A02C27527 | D0CFE900-8A25-BF6E-1125-018A02C226F0 | NAME_A | 1 | 3300.00 |
| C8529015-DC40-EA1E-36A1-018A02E3F088 | D0CFE900-8A25-BF6E-1125-018A02C226F0 | NAME_A | 2 | 500.00 |
| BE224ED1-A770-62C3-DB71-0185DDB1B62C | 2E1CE68A-5D4A-BBD8-021F-0185DDB0CB13 | NAME_B | -1 | 2500.00 |
| 95F1F307-143F-8864-A987-0185DDB1F457 | 2E1CE68A-5D4A-BBD8-021F-0185DDB0CB13 | NAME_B | 1 | 2500.00 |

I would be grateful for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing some sample data it's not possible to be be concise, however I suspect you could use a windowed aggregate for the column here:

```
..., max(GXTRADER.GXNAME) over(partition by FINENTRYGXID) as GXNAME,...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !
No need for sample data ! Your answer was right !